# R Package Check(): "All declared Imports should be used"

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

## Starting Situation:

I'm writing a small package of functions for myself only (not CRAN; on GitHub, but not public), and developing locally on the computer.  Mostly this is me being a newbie at R and learning to write first package.

I'm using `devtools` and after `load_all()` and `check()`, I have been getting this "NOTE":

```
-- R CMD check results -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MondelezR 0.1.0 ----
Duration: 21.1s

> checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
  Namespace in Imports field not imported from: 'tibble'
    All declared Imports should be used.

0 errors v | 0 warnings v | 1 note x
```

## Question:

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known/ expected problem that I can ignore?

## Little more background:

### I am using `tibble()`

In my package, "Find in Files" shows that I have used `tibble` in four files in different ways:

#### DESCRIPTION file:

```
[First Section of File Omitted]
Encoding: UTF-8
RoxygenNote: 7.2.0
Imports: 
    stringr,
    dplyr,
    purrr,
    tibble,
    magrittr
Suggests: 
    testthat (>= 3.0.0)
Config/testthat/edition: 3
```

(I have not seen the message for the other imported packages.)

#### FUNCTION: mdlz_otm_filter.R

```
[omitted]
#' @examples
#' df_otm_final <- tibble::tibble(
[omitted]
```

I am only using `tibble` in the example, not in the function itself, and the relevant portion is shown above.

#### DOCUMENTATION: mdlz_otm_filter.Rd

The roxygen2 documentation created from the above function shows the exact same example, but as documentation.

#### TEST THAT: test-mdlz_make_KEY1.R

```
test_that("POSTAL LANE2 works as expected", {

  df_test <- tibble::tibble(ORIG_ZIP = c("18615", "12345", "a5J 1u8"),
                            DEST_ZIP = c("1234", "23456", "i9y2b4"),
                            FINAL_KEY = c("18615-01234","12345-23456","A5J1U8-I9Y2B4"))

  expect_identical(mdlz_make_POSTAL_LANE(df_test$ORIG_ZIP,
                                         df_test$DEST_ZIP),
                   df_test$FINAL_KEY)
})
```

### Attempt to remove `tibble` from DESCRIPTION

I tried removing `tibble` from `Imports:` on the DESCRIPTION file, but as I expected would happen, I got this instead:

```
-- R CMD check results -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- MondelezR 0.1.0 ----
Duration: 26.6s

> checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... WARNING
  '::' or ':::' import not declared from: 'tibble'

> checking for unstated dependencies in 'tests' ... WARNING
  '::' or ':::' import not declared from: 'tibble'

0 errors v | 2 warnings x | 0 notes v
```

So... **warnings** are worse than **notes** I figure.

### Research:

Google search to start with brought me to these posts:

[RStudio Community Meta-Package](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-should-a-meta-package-handle-this-note-all-declared-imports-should-be-used/23400)  This guy's problem is that he needs to use functions in every package he's trying to put in his meta-package.  My issue is I'm already using `tibble` and getting the note regardless.

[SO devtools R CMD check NOTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487541/r-cmd-check-note-namespace-in-imports-field-not-imported)  But this one doesn't seem to apply because I **AM** using `tibble` in my package, and this guy is trying to remove it.

## Help?

I don't know how to clear the note, if I should worry about it at all, or why I'm getting it since I am using `tibble` as shown above.  Trying to learn, so an expository answer is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It likely means you have `tibble` in `Imports:` in `DESCRIPTION`, but are not actually importing it in `NAMESPACE`.  If you only use it in tests,  you could move it from `Imports:` to `Suggests:` (but should condition its use in tests via `if (requireNamespace("tibble", quietly=TRUE)) ....`)

Comment: You're right, it wasn't in `NAMESPACE`.  I added `#' @importFrom tibble "tibble"` and then `load_all()` and `check()` and it is now cleared because it has been added to `NAMESPACE`, but I don't understand why I need this for `tibble` and not for the other packages I'm using, like `dplyr` or `stringr`.  I think you're suggesting that my use in tests is treated differently than when I use it directly in functions I'm writing (?).  And examples are a different beast?  I'll go read some more.... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems devtools check function is looking for an importFrom tag with the package tibble in some of your function documentation [roxygen Docs](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html#imports).

Adding `@importFrom tibble tibble` to the functions documentation which use the library tibble might remove the note.